# Find specific item in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like this:

```
cardNumber: "2344234454562036"
cardType: "Visa"
cardholderName: "Yeyy"
cvv: "123"
expiryMonth: 12
expiryYear: 2022
postalCode: "52636"
redactedCardNumber: "••••••••••••2036"
__proto__: —'
```

I need to get the value of `redactedCardNumber` from that array.

The first thing that I am confused about is that when i print the above 'array' in the console, it actually show an **object** before everything! so is this an `array` or an `object`?

also, what is the best way of getting the specific item like '`redactedCardNumber`' from it?

Comment: that is very clearly an object... arrays are indexed by number... this is a list of properties.  How is this defined?

Comment: If it's an object, `theObject.redactedCardNumber`. If it's an array *containing* the object (for instance, at index `0`), `theArray[0].redactedCardNumber` (change the index as necessary). Details in the linked questions' answers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Thank you. I was confused and didn't know what it was! appologies for the useless question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an object. If so, you can access it by `obj.redactedCardNumber`.